# Content loading with jsonp

Tags: ajax, jsonp, sencha-touch-2

I am a beginner at sencha touch2. i am trying to create a some app which contains a blog view. the code of the blog is given below.  when i launch the app, the content fails to load, giving these errors.  i am using wamp for localhost.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load "  http://secureclick-media-maynemyltf.netdna-ssl.com/Extensions/rjs/c2.js".  Origin< http://localhost> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load  " http://api.yontoo.com/GetClientData.ashx?key=null&id=47a8564d-d089-4195-9564-72f107ea1c56&loc=http%3A//localhost/GS/&apps=bestvideodownloader,ezLooker,pagerage,buzzdock,toprelatedtopics,twittube".  Origin <http://localhost> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

> 

```
Ext.define('GS.view.blog',
{
        extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'blogpanel',

    config:{
        title: 'Blog',
        iconCls: 'star',

        items:
        {
            xtype:'list',
            itemTpl:'{title}',
            store:
            {   
                autoLoad: true,
                fields:['title','author','content'],

                proxy:
                {
                    type:'jsonp',
                    url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog',
                reader:
                {
                        type:'json',
                    rootProperty:'responseData.feed.entries',
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) service but a JSON one. You can detect it by calling [your URL](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog) from your browser and see the content isn't starting by a method call.

So you're not bypassing Cross-Domain protections.

You can't just tell the server you want it to answer in JSONP : it must be ready to make such an answer.

And your browser won't let you access from another domain a server answering in json and not having set a header specifying he accepts this cross-domain request. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control).

**EDIT :**

You may call this service using JSONP : you just have to specify a callback at the end of the URL.

> In addition to this response format, the protocol also supports a
>   classic JSON-P style callback which is triggered by specifying a
>   callback argument, which directs the API to deliver the JSON object as
>   an argument to the specified callback.

Example from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide) :

```
'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=Official%20Google%20Blogs&callback=processResults'
```

Comment: so how do i direct it to call back in jsonp